# How to launch CUSTOM(MY) APP from contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

I saw that Whatsapp can launch from contact. I tried the same and I can show my app logo inside contact connections, but when I click on icon there is no action.

How to achieve this?

Comment: You may do it using Intent. Read here- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: Hello Aishwarya, Thanks for the response. But using intent, we can call contact from our activity, but I need to call MY APP from CONTACTS_APP

Comment: Try this http://blogs.quovantis.com/syncing-contacts-with-an-android-application-2/?_sm_au_=isVkb0pkCNSJRsrM